# Как запустить MongoDB на нескольких серверах, чтобы mongo не была узким местом?

Tags: node.js, mongodb

Есть проект написанный с применением NodeJS и MongoDB.

Хотим запустить его на нескольких серврерах. Но появились вопросы по mongodb.

В случае, если использовать одну базу для всех серверов, думаем будет нагрузка и база просто не будет держать запросы со всех серверов.

В случае, если использовать для каждого сервера свою базу, то как распределять данные между остальными?

В случае репликации, как определять, что данные на слейвах уже появились и мы можем отправить пользователя на реплику?

Какие решения можно здесь применить?

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как принятый ^^"

Answer (score 0):

> В случае, если использовать одну базу для всех серверов, думаем будет
>   нагрузка и база просто не будет держать запросы со всех серверов.

Проблема в 1 ноде в общем случае не в этом. Реплки и т.п. придумали вообще больше для того, чтоб повысить redundancy. Не важно, что ваша база держит нагрузки. Если сервер упадёт, то у вас всё сломается. Концепция реплик с автоматическим фоловером была придумана, чтобы такие кейсы обрабатывать.

> В случае, если использовать для каждого сервера свою базу, то как
>   распределять данные между остальными?

Так себе решение. Ручками синхронить данные между этими базами?

> В случае репликации, как определять, что данные на слейвах уже
>   появились и мы можем отправить пользователя на реплику?

Для начала стоит определиться, действительно ли вам нужны дополнительные ноды из-за нагрузки?

1. Оптимизируйте базово, используйте пулы подключений и т.п.
2. Проведите тесты, посмотрите как оно справляется с текущими нагрузками.
3. В любом случае поднимите доп. ноды с автофоловером.

Что же касается "В случае репликации, как определять, что данные на слейвах уже появились". Я так понимаю, вопрос про "грязные данные"? Опять же:

1. Критичны ли эти данные? Если это, к примеру, сервис какой-то агрегированной статистики, то, возможно, вам не так важна актуальность и вы допускается немного устаревших данных, тогда можете спокойно читать с реплик.
2. Если, всё же, нужна консистентность данных, то можно указать так называемый write concern. На сколько я помню, если у вас 3 ноды, и вы укажите `w = 3`, то запрос на запись сообщит об успехе, только когда изменения будут закомичены на все реплики.